# EXTJS, How to Create data for XTemplate with JSON data that created by PHP

Tags: extjs

I hava a php variable that contain JSON type data.

```
$list = [{"id":"10","first_name":"first","mi_name":"","last_name":"last","nick_name":"HH"}];
```

and I need to use the date for EXT-JS XTemplate.

I tried this way,

```
var myStore = <?php echo $list; ?>;

var myTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    "<div style='text-align:center'>",
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<p> No : {#}</p>',
        '<p>{first_name} {$last Name}</p>',
    "</tpl>",
    "</div>",
    {}
);

var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    border : true,
    layout : 'fit',
    pageY : 10,
    items : new Ext.DataView({
        store : myStore,
        tpl : myTpl,
        autoHeight : true,
        emptyText : 'No Data'
    })
});
```

but it does not work,

also I tried this,

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    autoLoad : true,
    data : <?php echo $list; ?>
});
```

it does not work either.

so I tried to get the data using proxy.

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url : './index.php?action=getList' //it return same to $list
    }),
    fields : [
        {name : 'first_name', type : 'string'},
    {name : 'last_name', type : 'string'}
    ],
    autoLoad : true
});
```

and It works!

Hmm...

so my question is how can I create the data with JSON type php variable.
(I do not want to use proxy to get data if I can)

help me~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataview is missing the mandatory config "`itemSelector`"

For more info, please read the sencha documentation [Sencha ExtJS 4 dataview](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.View)